# How to copy non-empty cells from Excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, office-interop

I'm writing a C# app that pastes an Excel worksheet into a Word document.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];        
// select all then copy to clipboard
ws.get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn.Copy();
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
wordApp.Documents.Add();
wordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial(Link: true);
```

The code above works fine, but Word pastes objects as HTML by default and it messes up the document layout.

So I tried manual paste (ctrl-alt-v) and chose "Microsoft Office Excel 2003 Worksheet object" (expecting this can also be done by C#) and this time the whole worksheet (65535*65535 maybe) is pasted and the significant cells are minimized.

The worksheet contains charts and bitmaps so it's hard to calculate the cell coordinate just beneath the end of the charts/bitmaps.

Is there any shortcut to select only the non-empty cells in Excel?

Comment: Shapes (such as charts etc) have a TopLeftCell and a BottomRightCell property.  If you loop through all shapes you can calculate the range you need to copy (in conjunction with using the sheet's UsedRange property)

Comment: Are you just wanting to copy charts and bitmaps or also cells with values? Also, do you have to copy the sheet as is, or do you just want to export objects into word? What I mean is that actually copying a large sheet into word will make it very difficult to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any shortcut to select only the non-empty cells in Excel?*
- Yes. Try to do: `wholeRange = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, Type.Missing);` .To test this feature you can hit F5->Special.. and try another options.